# Error when compiling scala function

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a sort function in scala

```
def sort[A <: hw.generics.Ordered[A], C <: hw.generics.ListLike[A, C]](alist: C): C = {
    listLikeMatch[A, C](alist) match {
        case None => alist
        case Some((hd, tl)) => insert[A, C](hd, sort[A, C](tl))
        }
    }
}
```

This is the test I am running.

```
test("sort"){
        assert(sort[Ordered[Int],BinTree[Int]](unsortedTree) == tree)
    }
```

the compiler gives me this error. I can't figure out where the mistake is or what it even means.

```
[error] /home/student/generics/src/test/scala/testSuite.scala:24: type arguments [hw.generics.Ordered[Int],BinTree[Int]] do not conform to method sort's type parameter bounds [A <: hw.generics.Ordered[A],C <: hw.generics.ListLike[A,C]]
[error]         assert(sort[Ordered[Int],BinTree[Int]](unsortedTree) == tree)
[error]                    ^
[error] one error found
```

Comment: It would help to know what `hw` and `BinTree` are. In particular, probably `BinTree` is not a subtype of `ListLike`?